# Invalid trailing UTF-8 octet when working with Gems

Tags: ruby, utf-8, rubygems

I am getting this error every time I try to run a Ruby command in Terminal.  At this point, I can't even reinstall RVM.  The error looks like this:

```
/Users/ /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): invalid trailing UTF-8 octet at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /Users/ /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
```

This was also occurring when I had RVM installed.  If I tried to run any command like bundle update or anything that began with gem, I would get the same error.

Comment: Have you verified that there is no invalid continuation bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Just got feedback from another source and found out that it was actually an issue with rubygems, not bundler.  My ~/.gemrc file had some invalid bytes in it.  I just went into my .gemrc file and cleared it and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's an issue with bundler, try updating it manually

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8136

Comment: Hey Steven,

Thanks for the response.  I'm not too sure if it an issue with the bundler though as I don't even think I have bundler installed.  When I try 'bundle uninstall', I get the message: 'ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.'

At this point, I think it has something to do with my gems, but I can't even source a list of gems using 'gem list because I get the error message from my original post.

I might be completely wrong (I am very new to Rails), but if so, can you please give me some more detail on how to manually update my bundler?

Thanks again!

Comment: @jcaine To uninstall `bundler`, you would do `gem uninstall bundler`.